Is it necessory to attain higher Jhana to experience Nibbana?
Can some one experience nibbana just being in 1st Jhana. or 2nd..or 3rd..?
I read in one of sutta that to be arhant even 1st Jhana is sufficient.
But when someone becomes sotapanna, or higher Arya by just practicing 1st Jhana.then technically what happes?
(1) Either unknowingly and quickly he goes through 2,3,4,5,6,7,8, Jhana and then 9th.
(2) or he jumps 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and directly expirience 9th (Nibbana)

The Noble Eightfold Path contains four jhanas. Four jhanas is all that is necessary for Nibbana. The four immaterial spheres are optional. For example, in MN 140, the Buddha discourages a monk from developing the four immaterial spheres.
AN 4.123 is the only sutta I have read which gives the impression Nibbana can be attained with the 1st, 2nd or 3rd jhana. However, I think this sutta is incorrectly translated.

Thanks. your answers on Nibban seem appealing to me.

Firstly, nibbāna isn't ever taught by the Buddha to be a ninth jhāna. Mostly when people use this term they're referring to the cessation of perception and feeling.
Secondly, the Buddha explicitly says that not all arahants are capable of entering the formless states - these are what most people refer to as the fourth-eighth jhānas:

“And what is the individual (released) both ways? There is the case where a certain individual remains touching with his body those peaceful liberations that transcend form, that are formless, and—having seen with discernment—his effluents are ended. This is called an individual (released) both ways.4 Regarding this monk, I do not say that he has a task to do with heedfulness. Why is that? He has done his task with heedfulness. He is incapable of being heedless.
“And what is the individual released through discernment? There is the case where a certain individual does not remain touching with his body those peaceful liberations that transcend form, that are formless, but—having seen with discernment—his effluents are ended. This is called an individual who is released through discernment.5 Regarding this monk, I do not say that he has a task to do with heedfulness. Why is that? He has done his task with heedfulness. He is incapable of being heedless." MN 70

Therefore the idea that all these attainments need to be progressed through in order to attain the ending of effluents is unsupported by the suttas. What they do show needs to happen for this purpose is that intention and fabrication be totally dropped in order for the unfabricated to be experienced - and then that one can avoid developing any sense of passion or delight around that. When the Buddha describes the ending of effluents being attained from the first jhāna it seems that the meditator, on contemplating his state of concentration to the point of total dispassion, is intelligent enough to understand immediately that all fabrication is to be regarded in the same way and intuitively drop intentional activity in its entirety at that moment. Others drop the process more gradually - starting with verbal fabrications, then rapture, then pleasure, then breathing etc. thus leading them gradually through the different stages of concentration prior to their "plunging into the deathless."
The simile that occurs to me is this: it's like a mother with two sons, each boy holding a handful of stones, planning to throw them at passing cars. To stop them doing any harm with the stones she tells them of the consequences of doing so and then tells them to drop the stones. The smarter and more obedient child drops them all immediately, and they fall to the ground at once. The second, more reluctant and with a stronger urge to have some destructive fun, drops each stone one by one, yet nevertheless eventually drops them all to the ground like his quicker brother.

I downvoted this answer because I cannot find where the Buddha said "not all arahants are capable of entering the formless states".

Here you go - "There is the case where a certain individual does not remain touching with his body those peaceful liberations that transcend form, that are formless, but—having seen with discernment—his effluents are ended."

Hello. The sutta says "does not" rather than "cannot".

Yes. They do not because they cannot. They never learned to enter them, didn't need to in order to end the effluents, and on attaining arahantship any incentive to learn them is destroyed. Thus they literally cannot enter them.

This comment seems to be manufacturing its own teachings.

First of all, Jhana and Nirvana are two distinct aspects.
Jhana is about concentration. Nirvana is about understanding fundamental reality.
So no Jhana is required to achieve Nirvana. But having Jhana is an advantage to achieving Nirvana. It's because with a higher concentration of the Jhana mind understanding fundamental reality (aka Nirvana) is easier.


In Buddhism, there are 2 types of meditation.

Vipassana - understanding the true nature of the reality
Samatha - development of concentration of the mind

Vipassana brings happiness by reducing the attachment/Thanha to material or nun material objects.
Reaching Nirvana is the fullest state of this ultimate happiness.
Samatha brings happiness by,

attaching the mind to the focus object and satisfying with fulfilling this attachment
reducing 5 hindrances and reducing suffering generated out of these hindrances.

Reaching jhana is the fullest state of this happiness and this happiness is just satisfying the mind. (not an ultimate happiness).
